# Can Vector Space exist with differently defined operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

To check this out, I used Wikipedia site to check all axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). 
I'm struggling only with the 3rd and 4th:
3.) There exists an element $0$, such that: $0+a=$ (using definition) $= 0a = 0$. 
 So $0$ is now an element in the set.
But if I do: 
 $0+b= 0b = 0$

 $0+c= 0c = 0$ ...
This means an element $0$ exist for every element in the $R_{>0}$. So 3rd axiom is OK?
4.) $a + (-a) = -a^2 \ne 0$.

 Because 4th axiom doesn't hold true,  $R_{>0}$ is not a vector space.

Can you please help me to clear it up if this is correct?

Comment: In that case, the zero will be $1$. In fact, this is just the usual vector space $\Bbb R$ seen through the map $\exp \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R_{>0}$.

Comment: It's probably easier if you read that third and fourth axiom as "there is an element $z$ such that for all $v$, $v \oplus z = v$ and such that for all $v$ there is a $v'$ such that $v \oplus v' = z$".

Comment: In the second example $0a\neq 0$. From the definition, $\lambda\cdot a = a^{\lambda}$, so we have $0_\mathbb{R}a = a^{0_\mathbb{R}} = 0_V = 1\in R_{>0}$, where I denote the vector space $R_{>0}$ as $V$ for clarity. *That* is the identity. Don't mess up the $0$ between the "base" field ($0_\mathbb{R}$) and the identity within the vector space ($0_V = 1$).